# Assign a vertical alignment to a list box when selected //WP7 C# XAML

Tags: c#, list, xaml, windows-phone-7

When a list box item is selected, I would like for the selected item to become vertically centered on hit. I was hoping to add this to my c#. This is what I've got so far. I want the same to be applied to my secondary list box item (listBox1 AND listBox2).

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        //MessageBox.Show("Item selected: " + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            listBox2.ScrollIntoView(listBox2.Items[27]);

        }
    }


    private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Item selected: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: what if the number of items in the list is less than fit on the screen? Or what if the first or last item was selected? what should happen then?

Comment: what does your xaml look like for the list box?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance of something in different states I'd reccomend using the `VisualStateManager` and changing properties of the elements accordingly in the relevant state. In the instance of the items for your `ListBox`, you should probably change the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle%28VS.95%29.aspx).